# homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0,...,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Yesterday I did some self study about projective varieties in algebraic geometry. I found homogeneous ideal is a concept that is rather hard to understand. I googled it but most of the material online introduce concept via graded ring but the lecture notes I read introduced this from scratch.

**Definition** *An ideal $I\subset k[x_0,...,x_n]$ is homogeneous if for every $f\in I$, all the homogeneous components $f^{(i)}$ are in $I$*

**Proposition** *An ideal $I\subset k[x_0,...,x_n]$ is homogeneous if and only if it is generated by homogeneous elements*

My question is how to prove the only if part(Well, the writer claims it is trivial). By Hilbert's Basis theorem, all the ideals in $k[x_0,...,x_n]$ can be finitely generated since any field is a Noetherian ring(the only ideals are 0 and k so the chain will become stationary). So let ${f_1,...,f_r}$ be a set of generators, then by definition $f_j = \sum_{i=0}^{a_j}f_j^{(i)}$, where all $f_j^{(i)}$ are in $I$. But how could I select a set of generators so they are homogeneous i.e they have the same $(i)$?

Or maybe even more awarkward, my english is bad and did not understand this concept correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what you've written, $\{f_j^{(i)}\}$ is the homogeneous set of generators of $I$: each element is homogeneous, contained in $I$, and the ideal generated by them contains the $f_j$, which generate $I$. There's no requirement that all of the $(i)$ need to be the same, and in fact you cannot do this for all homogeneous ideals: for instance, $(x,y^2)\subset k[x,y]$ cannot be generated by any set of elements all of the same degree.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and nice explanation. I also thought about a similar example as you gave me, which caused me huge confusion.

Comment: Glad to help. Since you are new here, I wanted to let you know about accepting answers: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you. And I have accepted your answer.